# Converting Java code to PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a .pkb file (PL/SQL script) that in turn contains over 1000 lines of Java code. All the Java code is contained in one declaration below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "fnd_log_file_handler" AS
```

There are several libraries imported

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

The databases in my environment will not have JVM in the future causing this code to fail.

Can this code be directly translated into PL/SQL? Especially, considering the libraries that are being imported here. I'm not sure if they will be available in PL/SQL.

If not, what other options do I have?

Comment: Define "directly translated".  PL/SQL may have APIs (or the ability to build APIs) that do whatever it is that the Java code is doing.  But it is unlikely that it's going to be reasonable to convert it line-by-line rather than simply re-implementing the code based on the business requirements.  `java.util` will only exist in Java but PL/SQL may have functions that do basically the same things that the functions your code is using from that package is doing.

Comment: I meant that the PL/SQL code has to provide the same functionality as the existing Java code. java.util seems ok but I was unsure of xml parsing and dom manipulation and if it something that's performed in PL/SQL code.

Comment: Can you do XML manipulation in PL/SQL?  Sure.  Is the API going to be as easy to work with as the Java API?  That's impossible to say without knowing exactly what the Java code is doing.